Duplicate ActiveRecord Object and Associations across Databases
I am attempting to copy an ActiveRecord object with many deeply nested associations from one database to another at runtime. My application is using one database for runtime calculations and then exporting the data to multiple other consuming databases with identical schemas. My application is using ActiveRecord, but not using Rails.
I am able to connect to both databases using the following. Both databases are empty of records before running these tests.
connects_to database: {
  writing: {
    adapter: 'sqlite3',
    database: ':memory:'
  },
  reading: {
    adapter: 'sqlite3',
    database: ':memory:'
  },
  external_1: {
    adapter: 'sqlserver',
    database: 'externalDatabase',
    username: '...',
    password: '...',
    host: '...',
    port: '...'
  }
}

and have the following in my model
has_many :examples

amoeba do
  enable
end

Using no outside Gems
run = Models::Run.first
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :external_1) do
   run.save
end

Does not result in any errors, but also does not save either the run or any of its children to the external database.
I can verify the run Models::Run:0x00007fc2df77f430 id: 1, run_time: 1728340073
and its example Models::Example:0x00007fc2b8310650 id: 1, name: "test_name", run_id: 1 exist in the local database.
Using the amoeba Gem
run_copy = Models::Run.first.amoeba_dup
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :external_1) do
   run_copy.save
end

This results in the error TinyTds::Error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_rails_3cb46f584c". The conflict occurred in database "externalDatabase", table "examples", column 'id'. Nothing is saved to the external database.
I can verify the copy of the run doesn't populate or copy the primary key. Models::Run:0x00007fc2ff226ef0 id: nil, run_time: 1728340073, but the example seems to populate a foreign key for the run Models::Example:0x00007fc2ff2268b0 id: nil, name: "test_name", run_id: 24
Using the deep_cloneable Gem
run_copy = Models::Run.first.deep_clone(include: {examples: :example_childrens}, use_dictionary: true)
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :external_1) do
   run_copy.save
end

This results in the error ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'example_id', table 'example_childrens'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. Nothing is saved to the external database. I can verify the copy of the run doesn't populate or copy the primary key. Models::Run:0x00007fc2df77edc8 id: nil, run_time: 1728340073, but the example seems to populate a foreign key for the run Models::Example:0x00007fc2e8ef1318 id: nil, name: "test_name", run_id: 25 I cannot seem to navigate to the example_childrens as none of the associations appear to be connecte for any of the run_copy.examples.first.example_childrens

Any insight to any of these errors or a better way of copying a deeply nested object from one database to another would be greatly appreciated.
